# separating key-value pairs in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have been trying to import my mySQL database into Elasticsearch through Logstash but I am stuck (for two days now) to separate three columns into separate fields.

I want to split these into different fields so it displays as:

```html
"dr_behaviour_Patient Healer": "5", 
"dr_behaviour_Couldn’t Care Less": "5"
```

```html
filter {
  mutate {
    split => {
        "dr_behaviour_rate" => "," 
        }
    }
  kv {
    source => "dr_behaviour_rate"
    prefix => "dr_behaviour"
    field_split_pattern => "/[/]"
    include_brackets => true
  }
}
```

[this is how the original data is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfMER.png)

[I used the split-mutate filter to separate into an array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VITJd.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```
  kv {
source => "dr_behaviour"
prefix => "behaviour_"
field_split => ","
include_brackets => false
value_split => "\[\]"
trim_key => "\s\[\]"
trim_value => "\s\[\]"
```

}